# It keeps on giving me a name error when I try to make several branches

Tags: python

I'm trying to make several branches, and this keeps giving me this name error

I tried deleting the problems it gave me, and then I figured I was deleting the whole thing

```
while True:
    d1a = input ("Do you want to: A) Approach the house. B) Approach the stable. [A/B]? : ")
    # check if d1a is equal to one of the strings, specified in the list
    if d1a in ['A', 'B']:
        # if it was equal - break from the while loop
        break
if d1a == "A": 
    print ("You approach the cottage.") 
elif d1a == "B": 
    print ("You approach the stables.")
```

Errors: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in 
    d1a = input ("Do you want to: A) Approach the house. B) Approach the stable. [A/B]? : ")
  File "", line 1, in 
NameError: name 'A' is not defined

Comment: Please add your complete error message, as well as the steps to reproduce that error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are running Python 2, also called legacy Python. In that version of Python, `input` tries to *evaluate* the input. You input `A` so Python tried to find its value. There was no variable named `A` so you got the error message.

Use `raw_input` instead of `input`. Or better yet, move to Python 3. Your code works fine in my Python 3.7.3.